# best way to convert aspx dynamic pages urls in user friendly urls using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

what is the best way to convert aspx dynamic pages urls in user friendly urls using asp.net 2.0.

I want to convert **http://www.mydomain.com/product.aspx?Id=4** in to **http://www.mydomain.com/product4.aspx

Answer (score 4):

By using an url rewriting method! [Here's some](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2007/02/26/tip-trick-url-rewriting-with-asp-net.aspx) information from ScottGu.

You need the following:

- Actionless Form
- URL Rewriter Module for ASP.NET

Thats it, you want to find a simple one where you just add the regexped-routes in your web.config. If you want to remove the .aspx you can do this by changing in IIS. There's some info on this on ScottGu's blogg aswell!

Answer (score 0):

How about using [ASP.NET MVC](http://www.asp.net/mvc/)? You should be able to map that to a route pretty easily - either as `"product{id}"` or `"product/{id}"`. I personally would drop the `.aspx`, but that is up to you.

Comment: I'd vote for that too. But if he already have a complete system that is asp.net forms-based it'd be hell to rewrite all that for nice urls. Takes approx. 20 mins to implement an url rewriter. Takes weeks to re-code.

Comment: ehh 20 minutes is a stretch if you have to rewrite your links throughout the entire application, including form actions